# How to add integers and compare the result with number

Tags: android, eclipse, math, integer, logic

I have the following code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    int a1_val = 0;
    int b1_val = 0;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_goto_start);

        Button a1_btn =(Button)findViewById(R.id.a1_btn);
        Button b1_btn =(Button)findViewById(R.id.b1_btn);
        Button result_btn  =(Button)findViewById(R.id.result_btn);

        // a1 click
        a1_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                a1_val = 1;
            };
        });

        // b1 click
        b1_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                b1_val = 5;;
            };
        });

        result_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if { (a1_val + b1_val == 6);
                    View startpage = (View)findViewById(R.id.startpage);
                    startpage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }; 
            else break;
```

Why is the app crashing, when I click the result_btn? I think I made a mistake in the if statement, but I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: What did you try? You're just posting some random code, that shows some buttons...

Comment: Sorry I edited now, what I tried!

Comment: Can you post the error that is produced by this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I see are brackets of the IF statement, here's the fix:

```
if (a1_val + b1_val == 6) {
    View startpage = (View) findViewById(R.id.startpage);
    startpage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

And I think it's not the only problem here...

**EDIT - here's the whole posted code rewritten:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_goto_start);

        final Button a1_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.a1_btn);
        final Button b1_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1_btn);
        Button result_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.result_btn);

        // a1 click
        a1_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                v.setText(1);
            }
        });

        // b1 click
        b1_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                v.setText(5);
            }
        });

        result_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if ((Integer.parseInt(a1_btn.getText()) + Integer.parseInt(b1_btn.getText())) == 6) {
                    View startpage = (View) findViewById(R.id.startpage);
                    startpage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
        }
    // ... other code of Activity
```